# Receiving data in packets on TCP client

Tags: c++, tcp, client, winsock

Does recv() call intercepts data in packets or can i get data packets with timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

On a datagram socket (like UDP), `recv` gets data in datagrams.  TCP is a stream-mode socket, however, and `recv` gets a collection of bytes with no regard for packets.

It's possible, using low-level APIs, to get the packets, but if you were hoping to see boundaries between `send` calls you are out of luck... that information is not present in the packets.

Comment: Because if the messages were sent at the same time they would be transmitted in a single packet?

Comment: @user: Nagle can combine outgoing data, large buffers can be separated into multiple packets, packets can be fragmented due to MTU restrictions, and proxies can rebuffer data.  Even if Nagle is disabled, if a retransmit takes place (and it will, because this is how TCP manages bandwidth), as much data will be packed into a packet as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Recv gets data from a socket that has been successfully received.  It does not tell you when that happened; i.e. no timestamp.

Would you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve ("why do you need this?") instead of your attempted solution?  (Or have I completely misunderstood your question?)

Comment: I was wondering if recv can get the data in form of IP packets as sent from server but instead it seems to get as much as possible in same buffer, is that true?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Are you trying to access the raw IP headers?  You cannot do that with `recv()`, it only returns the data payload from inside the IP packets, not the complete IP packets themselves.

Comment: @user3234: Yes, recv gets the payload data represented as a stream  rather than as individual IP packets.  (Or a single message/packet for datagram sockets, but you specified TCP.)  For example, even if the data was received out of order, the system orders it appropriately and recv always gets the "next" data.

Answer (score 0):

If your own code is sending data to the remote machine where you are receiving data...then you can make you r own application level data format...such as sending the data after sending timestamp (some specified number of bytes).

This information can be extracted at the receiving end. Although as mentioned connection is TCP ...the data would be in stream format not as a complete packet as in case of UDP.